# Elevation/Shadow to a dialog for pre-21 or pre-lollipop

Tags: android, dialog, shadow, elevation, android-elevation

There are posts related to elevation for views for pre-lollipop devices. I applied techniques that could be applied to the dialog but I still can not have elevation/shadow to my dialog.

I tried this in the style but it did not work.

```
<item name="android:background">@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame</item>
```

ViewCompat.setElevation() and View.setOutLineProvider() methods are available from Lollipop. So can not use them.

I am not able to add the screeshots here for unknown reason. But the dialog is flat on KK and is elevated and look nice on Lollipop.

This is how I created dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AlertDialogStyle));
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
```

And AlertDialogStyle is just this:

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
</style>
```

Can you help me with any clue on how can I add elevation to dialog on pre-lollipop or pre-21 devices ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not an answer to the question but it is an alternative I had to do for things to work in app.

So, I've used [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) instead of dialog and changed my app theme from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```